# Is there a simple way to change the text of the 'Open' button on the windows file dialog to 'Select'?

Tags: windows, vb.net

We're using the file picker dialog to allow users to add documents into our application.  The word 'Open' doesn't make a lot of sense in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would browse the [code found here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/OpenFileDialogEx.aspx), which shows how someone extended the OpenFileDialog. Admittedly, this is overkill for you. But I think there is code within to change the button label.

Answer (score 0):

Not really no.

Given the standardization of this dialog it's extremely likely that your users will have used it many times in the past to "add" files to applications. The chances are they will be quite familiar with the implications of the word, changing it may be more confusing to them.

Answer (score 0):

The standardness of the dialog is why it's called a "Common File Dialog".  If you want to change it for your app, you'll have to write your own dialog.

Having said that, there are apps out there that can pull a form out of a DLL, modify it, and stick it back in.  However, this is a per-machine hack and downright bad form.